# parameterization with multiple @dataprovider to Test the "login and homepage" Test case as together

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

Hi I am new to Automation and I am trying to do a data parameterization of 'Login.java and HomePage.java' as together. And post the result in respective column in excel sheet.

Please find the Structure of excel as below.
[image]

Testcase for Login:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getTestData", priority=1 )
    public void testCaseLoginPage(String id , String pass  ) throws Throwable {
        boolean status = false;
        click("rj-qp-buynow");
        Thread.sleep(500);  ... So so 
}

@AfterMethod
    public void reportDataSetResult() {
         {
            isTestPass = false;
            TestUtil.reportDataSetResult(suitexls, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), count + 2, "FAIl");
        } else
            TestUtil.reportDataSetResult(suitexls, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), count + 2, "PASS");
            fail = false;
    }

@DataProvider (name="getTestData")
    public Object[][] getTestData() {
        return TestUtil.getData(suitexls, this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

Testcase for Home Page:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getData",  priority=2)
    public void testCaseHomePage(String AddDesign , String AddColor, String AddCity) throws Throwable {
 -------------- so so 
}

@DataProvider (name="getData")
    public Object[][] getTestData() {
        return TestUtil.getData(suiteixls, this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

TestNg.xml

```
<test name="com">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.Login"/>
        <class name="com.HomePage" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

With this current structure,  Login page get tested with multiple set to data. Once Login Page test is done, try to run the HomePage.java which end-up with big error.

Please let me know what changes I need to make to run these 2 testcases as together with multiple set of data?

Now getting Results as below:

```
test1@Qe.com - test
test1@Qe.com - test 
test1@Qe.com - OOOO
test1@Qe.com - test
test1@Qe.com - test
bluePage  Blue  Pune
WhitePage   Black   Mumbai 
PinkPage   Yellow Jaipur
```

Where want a get output in this below format :

```
   test1@Qe.com - test  
    bluePage  Blue  Pune
    test1@Qe.com - test  
     WhitePage   Black   Mumbai 
    test1@Qe.com - OOOO  
     PinkPage   Yellow Jaipur
    test1@Qe.com - test    
     Na       NA      NA
    test1@Qe.com - test 
   NA       NA      NA
```

Please suggest

Comment: What is that big error ?

Comment: Share the code for TestUtlis.getData()

Comment: Big Error :-  after completion of login test , it is trying to directly go to HomePage(without login test). But since login test is not run (as it already completed  ) script is not able to reached to Home Page. endup with Element not fund error.

Comment: TestUtlis.getData() is working fine. I am getting test data correctly from this method

Comment: testCaseLoginPage() and testCaseHomePage() are in same class file ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try in different ways, i could suggest

1. Create method for login may be in page class if you are using page object model with required arguments to pass
2. Use same method in login test case
3. Call same method in Home test case initially and then home related methods
4. Update Home sheet in xlsx file with data which required for login.Here you can take advantage of passing different login details for respective test data row.